# Estimate of semigroup with dual norm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Consider a semigroup $(T(t))_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+}$ generated by a densely defined strictly positive symmetric linear operator $A: D(A) \subset X \to X$, where $X$ is a Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Besides, we introduce a Sobolev scale $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb
{Z}}$ induced by completion of $D(A^\infty)$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_n:=\|A^n\cdot\|$, in particular $\|\cdot\|_0 = \|\cdot\|$.

My question is, under what conditions, there exists estimates such that

> for $t\in (0,T)$, some $a >0$, $\|T(t)x\|_0 \leq C \|x\|_{-a}$, or
>     $c \|x\|_{-a}\leq\|T(t)x\|_0 \leq C \|x\|_{-a}$.

In alternative, one may consider the weaker version, $t\in (t_0,T)$ with fixed $t_0>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if $A$ is symmetric, then $X$ should be a Hilbert space, but I remain in a Banach space.

If 
$$\|T(t)x\| \leq C\|A^{-1} x\|$$ 
holds for all $x\in X$, then using the substitution $y=A^{-1}x$, you obtain
$$\|AT(t)y\|\leq C\|y\|.$$

But by Theorem 5.3 in Section 2.5 of

*A. Pazy*, MR 710486 [**Semigroups of linear operators and applications to partial differential equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-5561-1), ISBN: 0-387-90845-5.

this implies that $A$ is bounded. Hence, I do not see much of a chance for your inequalities to hold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which theorem do you mean? They are numbered within the chapter so there are multiple theorem 5.3.

Comment: @newbie: thanks. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: That theorem actually requires $AT(t)$, inflated by $\frac{1}{t}$ to be bounded as $t\to 0$. I think it is stronger than the boundedness of $AT(t)$. Besides, according to Theorem 4.6, chapter II, from [One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387984636), in the proof (e) $\Rightarrow$ (c), $AT(t)$ is always bounded.

Comment: You misunderstand something quite. From what you cite, it follows that $\|AT(t)\|\leq C(t)$. You require $C$ to be independent of $t$. But for analytic semigroups, $C(t)\approx \frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: What I cite allows $\|AT(t)\|$ to go to $\infty$ like $\frac{1}{t}$, it is much weaker than boundeness.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So given that $\|AT(t)\|\lesssim 1/t$, for $t\in (t_0,T)$ with $t_0>0$, $AT(t)$ is a bounded operator, can we also achieve the other direction?

Comment: You asked for $t_0=0$...

Comment: Yes, I did. Since it is not the case, I am looking for some local version of it. But yet, thanks for the help and I'm going to accept the answer.